# Using App Engine Datastore over MySQL for a CRM System

Tags: google-app-engine, architecture, crm, google-cloud-datastore, mysql-python

I am about to take on a project, and I will to ask which database is best to use to build and develop a CRM System that does a lot of reporting and calculations for an Advertisement company.
My choices are MySQL and the Google App Engine Datastore (NoSQL). Left to me I want to use the Datastore but am concerned about the constant reporting and constant calculations on the CRM System.
please advice.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider google datastore [limits](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits) in your analysis:

There is no aggregate functions in datastore, you won't be able to do `group by`.

Try both (PoC), and you'll find out which fits best your use case.